# Rails Tutorial 3.3.4 - "mv: foobar: No such file or directory"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, tdd

I am following Hartl's Tutorial and am confused as to why I am getting this error. I am trying to eliminate duplication in my code by embedding ruby in my layouts. To do this, I follow the tutorial's instructions and I enter the command:

```
$ mv foobar app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
```

and in return, I see:

```
mv: foobar: No such file or directory
```

My questions are:

1) What does "foobar" mean?
2) How do I fix/get past this error?

Please let me know if this requires more context and/or code. Thanks.

Comment: The answer is too long to be written here. `Google` Foobar. The light will come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foobar` is a generic name. It is most likely used as a placeholder.

`mv` is a command that moves a file from a source to a destination

```
mv <source> <destination>
```

This means that tutorial tells you to move the file `foobar` to `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.

Obviously you don't have a file named foobar. Either you have to create it or it stands for another file that you already have.

Comment: Ah that explains a lot! Thanks, I will try this and let you know what happens.